# How to install veloEclipse in eclipse mars

Tags: eclipse-plugin, velocity

I need a velocity editor for eclipse mars. I tried to install Velo Eclipse, but was unsuccessful. Can any one tell me how to install velo eclipse or any other velocity editor

Comment: From the comments on the [market place entry](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/veloeclipse) it looks like this plugin is very out of date.

Comment: is there any other velocity editor for eclipse mars

Answer (score 2):

As to your question: 'is there any other velocity editor for eclipse mars'

> Velocity UI 1.0.5

works in Mars 4.5.1. Unlike Velo Eclipse the content assist just supports VTL elements but no html tags. Anyway, it works fine and stable.

It's not in the market place, think I installed it by `Help > Install New Software > Work with 'Velocity UI - http://veloedit.sourceforge.net/updates/'`.

Update:
Ver. 1.0.8 is available and works in Eclipse Neon (4.6.3).

Comment: One also needs to restart eclipse with option -clean after installation